# "What time is it" by dragging the pointer

Tags: qt, qml, drag, snapping, mousearea

I'm trying to implement a small didactic program written in Qt, that uses QML as I'm learning in parallel.

I'd like to know if it is possible to get the real time during the circular drag of the clock pointer. Would you recommend to start with that "customizing dial" from Qt?

It will be just a clock with hour pointer (with interval of 1h).

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend customizing Dial, as it has a fixed angle range limit of -140 to 140. You need 360 degrees of rotation that doesn't start or stop anywhere per se. As such, IMO you need a completely custom implementation.

Comment: The task can be easily implemented as a custom item. In my experience that will take less time and will work faster and more stable. Customizing some ready item will not be so flexible. Especially if all this for training purposes.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Yes. I would need the pointer snapping to each hour interval. That's exactly what I'm trying to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to customize the code below in order to get the handler outside the circle and if possible to replace it by a svg image with triangle shape. Switching the interval to 1h instead of seconds will also be a challenge. Not working so far... :)

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle{
    id: root;
    width: 720;
    height: 480;
    color: "black";

    Item {
        id: container;
        width: 250;
        height: width;
        anchors.centerIn: parent;

        property real centerX : (width / 2);
        property real centerY : (height / 2);

        Rectangle{
            id: rect;
            color: "white";
            transformOrigin: Item.Center;
            radius: (width / 2);
            antialiasing: true;
            anchors.fill: parent;

            Rectangle {
                id: handle;
                color: "red";
                width: 50;
                height: width;
                radius: (width / 2);
                antialiasing: true;
                anchors {
                    top: parent.top;
                    margins: 10;
                    horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
                }

                MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onPositionChanged:  {
                        var point =  mapToItem (container, mouse.x, mouse.y);
                        var diffX = (point.x - container.centerX);
                        var diffY = -1 * (point.y - container.centerY);
                        var rad = Math.atan (diffY / diffX);
                        var deg = (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
                        if (diffX > 0 && diffY > 0) {
                            rect.rotation = 90 - Math.abs (deg);
                        }
                        else if (diffX > 0 && diffY < 0) {
                            rect.rotation = 90 + Math.abs (deg);
                        }
                        else if (diffX < 0 && diffY > 0) {
                            rect.rotation = 270 + Math.abs (deg);
                        }
                        else if (diffX < 0 && diffY < 0) {
                            rect.rotation = 270 - Math.abs (deg);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Text {
            text: "%1 secs".arg (Math.round (rect.rotation / 6));
            font {
                pixelSize: 20;
                bold: true;
            }
            anchors.centerIn: parent;
        }
    }
}
```